# mysql timestamp diff has unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, mysql-workbench

While I try to get the diff of two mysql timestamps, I have got unexpected results in some cases.

You can see, that in the result of the first query are 2 timestamps. If I do the diff manually, I'll get 47ms.
[image: query1]

Now I execute the second query, and you can see, that the result is totally wrong.

Most interestingly, this just happens not always, most of the time the result is correct.

[image: query2]

---

Now lets have a look on a correct result - same query only other row.

The diff manually calculated is 79ms.

[image: query3]

And indeed the result of mysql is correct.

[image: query4]

---

What is going on here?

MySQL Bug?

Thanks!

---

Here is the result of an additional test.

I have found that the issue always happens when the minute changes.

[image]

Comment: can you manually change the data to test this theory: I think it could be that it only appears when the second timestamp ticks over a full second, or over a full minute -- that's the only difference i can see between those two sets of data.

perhaps a result set of like 20+ examples would be more useful, so we can potentially find the patterns, and work out what is going on?

Comment: yes, there is a pattern. I have edited my question with an extract that details the pattern.

Comment: Try using `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` instead of `-`.

Comment: You cannot subtract timestamps that way. You can either use `timestampdiff` or convert them to `unix_timestamp`.